# Javascript/jQuery [object Object] when trying to find great-grandparent class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a great-grandparent div class name using the .closest method of jQuery. But when I test to make sure the correct div class name is being passed, I just get an [object Object] alert, which appears to be some sort of error. This code is meant to be able to find the div class with name beginning 'form-container' regardless of number of div's between (this) and the desired div. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('input').bind('blur', function () {
                    var className = $(this).closest('.form-container');
                    alert(className + "ClassName");
                    var newClass = className.replace('.form-container', '');
                    alert(newClass);
                    alert("Hello");
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Clicked Inputs', name + " " + newClass, pathname);
</script>
```

Comment: `.closest` returns a jquery **object**, not a class name. That's why you get that output. It's not an actual error. Search for how to get the classes from a jquery object. Tip: reading documentation usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var className = $(this).closest('.form-container');
```

doesn't return a name. It returns the nearest object *matching* that name.

If you want to *see* the class attribute from that object, use:

```
 alert( className.attr('class') );
```

Answer (score 1):

$(‘input’) this will match all kind of input types like, buttons, text, email, password, etc… buttons doesn't have blur event as far as I know, you can bind click to them instead.

The use of bind should be replaced by on method. …on(‘blur’… to emulate the bind method or $(document).on(‘blur’, ‘input’… to emulate a live method. bind and live method are old. :(

You receive an [object Object] because the className variable is an object, if you want to see the class name in the alert message use:

```
alert(className.attr('class'));
```

if you want to remove a class use jQuery like className.removeClass(‘name’) and to add className.addClass(‘name’).

If you want to improve performance use an ID on the tag like:

```
<form id=“some” class=“form-container”>
```

and refer to the ID with #some.

If you can't refer the ID you could be more specific in your selector using form.form-container.

Some tips you could find useful.